# How to dynamically displays a div tag using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with my code? It doesn't shown what i am expecting. This is what my code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  ...
  $('input[name=hdr_approval]').change(function(){
    if($('input:radio[name=hdr_approval]')[0].checked == true){
      $('#stage-action').css('display', 'block');
    }else{
      $('#stage-action').css('display', 'none');
    }
  });

  if($('input[name=hdr_approval]:checked').length > 0 || $('#stage').val() === 'Personal Qualification Data'){
    $('#stage-action').css('display', 'block');
    console.log(document.getElementById("stage").value);
  }else{
    $('#stage-action').css('display', 'none');
  }

  console.log(document.getElementById("stage-action").style.display);
  ...
});
```

Here is the chunk of my page:

```
<div class="col s6 m6 l6 body-reset">
    <div class="right-align col s11 body-reset" style="height: inherit !important;">
        <p id="stage-text" class="custom-stage-text" style="height: inherit !important; top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; ">
            @switch($application->stage)
            @case('Credential Review')
            {{ 'Personal Qualification Data' }}
            @break
            @case('Personal Qualification Data')
            {{ 'Proceed to Qualifying Exam' }}
            @break
            @endswitch
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-align col s1">
        <button type="submit" id="stage-action" name="action_submit" form="lt-edit-form" class="btn-flats box"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

by default my `stage-action` display is set to none.

My logs is outputting what is supposed to be done but i can not figure out why `stage-action` is not displayed on my page.

Comment: Without the relevant HTML it is really hard to tell!!!

Comment: I have added some of my code.

Comment: @AnirudhLou - You mean even though the console log for `document.getElementById("stage-action").style.display` is `block` still the element is not shown in the `html`?.

Comment: Yes and on my if statement it meet one of the condition on my log it output block.

Comment: `$('input[name=hdr_approval]:checked').length > 0 || $('#stage').val() === 'Personal Qualification Data'` - neither of these condition is true, so it's set to `display: none;` (I put your code in a snippet here to see what happens). If you set `$('#stage-action').css('display', 'block');` instead of `none`, then the checkbox appears.

Comment: @AnirudhLou - It seems like again the `stage-action` display is set to `none`. Can you please reproduce the issue? This `if($('input:radio[name=hdr_approval]')[0].checked == true){` can also be written as `if($('input:radio[name=hdr_approval]')[0].checked)`.

Comment: the value of my ```stage``` div is from my database, in fact it is defined as ```<input type="hidden" id="stage" name="stage" value="{{ old('stage') ?? $application->stage }}">```.

Comment: On my log. It displays ```Personal Qualification Data``` and ```block``` but i don't know why it is not showing my div on my browser.